# Will a uniform plate of mass falling horizontally to a flat floor be decellerated just before touching the floor?

Tags: pressure, aerodynamics

If we look at a plate of mass, uniform in thickness and uniform in mass density, falling horizontally to a flat floor, experience a little deceleration just before touching the ground?

I can imagine the air beneath the plate before impact has no time enough to escape and creates a short period of a little higher air pressure as the atmospheric pressure, which causes a little deceleration.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for exactly the reasons you describe.  You can do related experiments with sheets of plywood (it is hard to find ones which are flat enough, and you also need a very flat floor) which, if you are skilful, you can get to skate across the floor in after you drop them, alarming cats.

Note: in the 'dropping horizontally' case I am not sure that the thing is stable: I think that the thing likes to 'fall off' the air underneath it, if that makes sense.  My 'experiments' with this (which really were just idle playing with materials in an empty ballroom) involved letting the sheet of plywood fall over from vertical, so not quite the same thing.

Comment: You can use a sheet of paper and see the effect.

Comment: @JMac Heh, yes, I used to do that at school!

Comment: Use styrofoam - it is reasonably flat and much lighter than plywood. With styrofoam the effect is very pronounced.